# MediaPlayer continue playing only when specific activity starts

Tags: java, android

I have a Mediaplayer of background music for my activity. I want to pause it and reset it when new activity starts and stop it when the activity destroys.

I did it like that:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
        if(!continiue){
            continiue=true;
    try{
        if (m != null) {
            m=new MediaPlayer();
                m.reset();
                m = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
                m.start();
        m.setLooping(true);
        }
        else{
            m.start();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onResume();
        }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try{
    if(m!=null){
        m.stop();
        m.release();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    super.onStop();
} 
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    try{
    if(m.isPlaying()){
        m.pause();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

This worked fine. Now I want to add another activity but I want the music to continue playing only when this specific activity opens. How can I do that?

Comment: you have else branch when m is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class only for music playing and rule it from Activities. Something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackgroundMusicPlayer {

    private static MediaPlayer mp = null;

    private static int playingResId;

    public static boolean isSoundTurnedOff;

    private static boolean isPaused;

    /** Stop old sound and start new one */
    public static void play(Context context, int resIdToPlay) {

        if (isSoundTurnedOff || context==null)
            return;

        if (mp != null && playingResId==resIdToPlay) {
            if (isPaused)
                mp.start();
            isPaused = false;
            return;
        }

        stop();

        Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "pause");
        context.sendBroadcast(i);

        playingResId = resIdToPlay;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resIdToPlay);
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        } else 
            Log.e("BackgroundMusicPlayer","Cant create MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer.create(context: "+context+", resIdToPlay: "+resIdToPlay+") returns null");


    }

    /** Stop the music */
    public static void stop() {

        if (mp != null) {
            isPaused = false;
            playingResId = 0;
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }

    public static void pause() {

        if (mp != null){
            mp.pause();
            isPaused = true;
        }
    }

    public static void resume() {

        if (mp != null && isPaused){
            mp.start();
            isPaused = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh! I can call a service - you're right, I completely forgot that exists!

Comment: Wait, but what is better, doing what you showed or creating a service? both do the same thing from what I understand..

Comment: I see no need to use service, also controlling the service is more complicated comparing to 4 public static methods available anywhere anytime.